# representing gregorian Calendar in a toString method

Tags: java, datetime, tostring, gregorian-calendar

So i have two classes, one with a toString method and I need one of the fields it prints to be the date and time, but I'm having a hard time doing it. Here is my email class(basic fields, constructors, getters and setters:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

public class Email {

private String to;
private String cc;
private String bcc;
private String subject;
private String body;
private GregorianCalendar timestamp;    //time that email was created



public Email(String to, String cc, String bcc, String subject, String body) {
    super();
    this.to = to;
    this.cc = cc;
    this.bcc = bcc;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.body = body;
    timestamp  = (GregorianCalendar) new GregorianCalendar().getInstance();


}
public String getTo() {
    return to;
}
public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}
public String getCc() {
    return cc;
}
public void setCc(String cc) {
    this.cc = cc;
}
public String getBcc() {
    return bcc;
}
public void setBcc(String bcc) {
    this.bcc = bcc;
}
public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
public String getBody() {
    return body;
}
public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp.getTime();
}
public void setTimestamp(GregorianCalendar timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

And here is my Folder class which contains Email objects. I have taken only an except of this method to make it simpler to look at:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.*;

public class Folder implements Comparable{

private ArrayList<Email> emails; 
private String name;
private String currentSortingMethod; 

 //constructors, getters, setters and other methods omitted

 public String toString(){
     String a = "";
     int j = 1;
     for(int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++){
         String k = Integer.toString(j);
         a += String.format("%-8s %-5s %-8s %-1s %10s", "  "+ k +"   ", "|" ,  emails.get(i).getTimestamp(), "|",  emails.get(i).getSubject()+ "  \n");
         j = Integer.parseInt(k);
         j++;
     }

             return(String.format("%-8s %-5s %-8s %-1s %10s", "Index", "|", "Time", "|", " Subject") + "\n" + "-------------------------------------\n" + a);
 }
```

the toString method should print something like this

```
Index    |     Time     |    Subject
-------------------------------------
  1      |     Time     |       e  
  2      |     Time     |       d  
  3      |     Time     |       c  
  4      |     Time     |       b  
  5      |     Time     |       a
```

it works fine for the other fields, but I need the "Time" column to be filled with the time stamps of when that email object was created. 
Example:  12:38PM 4/8/2012

Thank you so much for any help at all!

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `SimpleDateFormat`, basically, or the date/time facilities of `String.format`... have you tried anything so far? Also note that if your question is really "How can I convert a `GregorianCalendar` into a `String` in a particular format?" then 95% of the detail you've provided in the question is irrelevant.

Comment: could you explain how to use simpleDateFormat in this context? and would it work as a string in the String format or would that require a conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this locally and it works.. see below. what are u getting in ur timestamp field ?

```
Index    |     Time     |    Subject
-------------------------------------
  1      |     Fri Aug 12 18:16:59 PDT 2016 | subject  
  2      |     Fri Aug 12 18:17:00 PDT 2016 | subject
```

Comment: That would be perfect, but I'm getting an error saying "The method getTimestamp() is undefined for the type 
 Email"

Comment: not sure can u remove the import java.sql.Timestamp and check ? and also i notice that in the Email constructor u just have timestamp instead of this.timestamp not that it should matter but

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure which one did it, but i changed those two things you said and now i get the date. Thank you so much!